# How to increase decrease a button for a while in tkinter?

Tags: tkinter, button

I am new here, and a beginner in (at) Python 3.x

I am trying to create in tkinter a `Button` or two, when I click on the 1st button for example a third or forth button will increase and decrease (using width 16 and 18) 10 times, and after 10 times it return to being a normal button. Without using a `class`.

Code:

```py
from tkinter import *
import time
window1 = Tk()
window1.geometry("300x300")
btn1=Button(text="16",font=40,width=16)
btn1.pack()

# here I want to create a loop to flash the button 10 times
# I don't know which way is better :
# to use time.sleep with for in range or use .after
# or use def with loops
#can I put line 14 and 13 together ?!
#why the first button in line 5 does not appear instantly !? why line17 affect 
that so I put #?
btn1["width"]=18
btn1["text"]="18"
btn1.pack()
#time.sleep(1)
btn1["width"]=16
btn1["text"]="16"
btn1.pack()
window1.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would be better if you show us what you have done so far.

Comment: Use `config()` method to update the properties of a widget later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here use this:

```py
from tkinter import *


def change(event=None):

    global count
    
    btn2['width']= 18
    btn2.after(500, lambda: btn2.config(width=16))

    if count< 10:
        btn2.after(1000, change)
        count += 1 
        
    else:
        count=0
        
window1 = Tk()
window1.geometry("300x300")

count = 0

btn1=Button(text="btn1",font=40,width=16)
btn1.pack()
btn1.bind('<Button>', change)


btn2=Button(text="btn2",font=40,width=16)
btn2.pack()

window1.mainloop()
```

Comment: It would be better to have some explanation on.

Comment: @MoneymBrussel made an edit. Tell me whether that's what you were looking for I'll add an explanation.

Comment: Thank you, that's what i am looking for, now i will start to give some modifications that i want, thanks a lot.